# Create new variable using ifelse statement in R

Tags: r, date, if-statement

I would like to create a new variable using and ifelse statement and the following data:

```
   ID    Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column 4     Column 5 
   Ann        1           Y            A     2000-10-15  2000-10-14
   Ann        1           N            A     2000-10-16  2000-11-14
   Ben        1           Y            B     2000-10-11  2000-11-14
   Ben        2           Y            B     2000-11-13  2000
   Fred       1           N            A     2000-11-11  2000-11-15
   Jenny      1           Y            A     2001-11-12  2000-10-14
   Jenny      1           Y            A     2001-11     2000-11-15
```

By ID, I would like to to find the last complete date if it fits certain criteria. The criteria would be only select last date if it is 1 in Column 1, and A in Column 3 otherwise leave blank. The second criteria I would like to use is by ID, if Column 3 is B, keep that B date. So it would look like this:

```
   ID    Column 1      Column 2   Column 3   Column 4   Column 5    Column 6 
   Ann        1           Y            A     2000-10-15  2000-10-14 2000-10-15
   Ann        1           N            A     2000-10-16  2000-11-14
   Ben        1           Y            B     2000-10-11  2000-11-14 2000-11-14
   Ben        2           Y            B     2000-11-13  2000
   Fred       1           N            A     2000-11-11  2000-11-15
   Jenny      1           Y            A     2001-11-12  2000-10-14 2001-11-12
   Jenny      1           Y            A     2001-11     2000-11-15
```

I believe the if statement would go something like this but there could be a better way. Additionally, my lastcompletedate function isn't complete:

```
 ifelse(Column 1 == 1 & Column 3 == "Y", lastcompletedate(Column4), 
 ifelse(Column 2 == 'B', lastcompletedate(Column5), "") 
 lastcompletedate <-ddply(df,.(ID), tail,1)
```

Comment: This looks like a good use case for `dplyr::case_when`.

Comment: Please, can you explain the criteria in more detail. What do you mean by "last date"? What is the `lastcompletedata` function supposed to do? Currently, `ddply(df,.(ID), tail,1)` returns the last row for each `ID`. But, in your expected result for `ID` == "Ann `Column 6` contains `2000-10-15` in row 1 which is copied from `Column 4`, row 1 instead of `2000-10-16` from `Column 4`, row 2.